# Internet explorer shows gibberish for save/open file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, internet-explorer, fiddler

I have this C# code which downloads a file from server :

```
 public static void DownloadBinaryFile(byte[] _ByteArray, string fullfileName)
        {
             fullfileName = "רועי.pdf"; //"Royi.pdf" in hebrew
             System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fullfileName);
             System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(_ByteArray);
             System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
             System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
             System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

*Notice that filename has a fixed value ( for testing).*

When I click a button :

[image]

I DO see in FIDDLER the right name :

[image]

And Chrome *does* shows the right filename to save :

[image]

But Internet explorer shows gibberish :

[image]

Additional Information :

IE 11 , windows 7 64bit , Edge :

[image]

Page encoding :

[image]

**Question:**

Why does the  filename shown as gibberish and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't use non-ASCII characters inside Content-Disposition without additional escaping. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#disposition.parameter.filename.

Comment: Thank you.[It is now working as expected](http://i.imgur.com/u98FJXF.png). I added  `contentDisposition = "attachment;filename*=UTF-8''" + Uri.EscapeDataString(fullfileName);`.